# What would synthetic linear algebra look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, type-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

I'm aware of synthetic mathematical fields like synthetic differential geometry and synthetic topology where the area is developed axiomatically rather than deriving everything analytically from a foundation of sets.

So I'm wondering if a synthetic linear algebra would make sense or if that's trivial. Is linear type theory essentially the same thing?

Comment: = working in an abelian category with a bunch of nice properties?

Comment: @darij: that captures "additive" behavior but not "multiplicative" behavior (e.g. determinants). We really want to be working in a symmetric monoidal abelian category. See https://mathoverflow.net/a/243534/290 for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J.N. Oliveira and friends have a number of papers that give an axiomatisation of linear algebra.

The important observation is that matrices cannot be arbitrarily multiplied and as such do not form *monoids*, so the traditional mathematical approach of using monoids, groups, rings, fields does not easily apply here.

Matrices have *types*, or *dimensions*, that specify when they can be multiplied.

> *Slogan:* **Categories are Typed Monoids!**

One rather accessible paper might well be *Matrices As Arrows! A Biproduct Approach to Typed Linear Algebra*, or see [http://www4.di.uminho.pt/~jno/html/jnopub.html](http://www4.di.uminho.pt/%7Ejno/html/jnopub.html) for more similar such papers.

The abstract of the mentioned paper includes:

> Motivated by the need to formalize generation of fast running code for linear algebra applications, we show how an index-free, calculational approach to matrix algebra can be developed by regarding matrices as morphisms of a category with biproducts. This shifts the traditional view of matrices as indexed structures to a type-level perspective [...]
>
> From errant attempts to learn how particular products and coproducts emerge from biproducts, we not only rediscovered block-wise matrix combinators but also found a way of addressing other operations calculationally such as e.g. Gaussian elimination. A strategy for addressing vectorization along the same lines is also given.

Comment: Obviously it wouldn't have matrices... So don't worry about that..

Answer (score 0):

It would look like something out of principia. Instead of vectors being coordinated, one would have to define linear operators in terms of basic "geometric algebra".